# Processing: Play video whilst loading images into array

Tags: processing

I am using processing to play image sequences (amongst other stuff) and have an issue in that when the image sequences are too big or I have too many loading at sketch startup I run out of memory (even after tweaking settings). If there is a way round the above where I can load everything on sketch startup that would be ideal however I have come to the conclusion this is not possible meaning I will have to load items before I used them.

This takes some time (around 8 seconds) and I would like to play a loading video or similar whilst this is going on.

Is there anyway to do this? At the moment the whole sketch just freezes while the app cycles the for loop loading the new image sequence and then continues. Starting a video just before does not work as it simple freezes because Draw() is no longer looping.

Tiny bit of my code below.

```
//loadRed
void loadRed() {
for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i += 2) {
String imageName = "f1red"+ nf(i, 4) + ".jpg";
images[i] = loadImage(imageName);
println("Loading - " + imageName);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution to this so going to link here hopefully might help somebody out in the future!

http://processing.org/tutorials/data/

Scroll down to Threads and this will allow asynchronous functions to run.

Hope this helps someone. Will